# ReactJS component not rendered on ajax paginated pages in django

Tags: ajax, django, pagination, reactjs

I am using ReactJS to render a like/unlike component for an object in a django project. I have a list page where I have a list of objects and for each object I render a `LikeUnlike` component as follows:

```
<div class="object">
    <span id="likes-service-{{service.pk}}"></span>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        React.render(<LikeUnlike object_id="{{service.pk}}" app_label="providers" model_name="providerservice" like_count="{{service.like_count}}" liked="{% user_has_liked 'providers' 'providerservice' service.pk request.user.pk  %}" />, document.getElementById("likes-service-{{service.pk}}"));
    </script>
</div>
```

On the very first page every thing works. The component renders and works as expected. The issue comes in when I scroll down and the second page is loaded via ajax (as I am using `django-endless-pagination`). For any pages loaded via ajax, the component is not rendered and all I see is a blank `<span id="likes-service-{{service.pk}}"></span>` element.

I have tried logging `document.getElementById("likes-service-{{service.pk}}")` and few other things and seems like the element, React library etc. are available.

I can't figure out why the component is not rendered when the page is loaded via ajax. Any Ideas ?

Comment: You're filling in the data via Django templates on the initial page load, correct? Hence when the page updates dynamically, no additional rendering is taking place, and you end up with template tags instead of data. I don't see any actions in your component that are making an AJAX request on their own?

Comment: As mentioned I use `django-endless-pagination` which via ajax bring in the rendered HTML. so each time a new page is loaded `render` method is called on a template with the updated list and the rendered HTML is then return to AJAX which is then inserted into the DOM.

Comment: The point is that same render method works on the page load but when rendered HTML data is returned via ajax the component is missing.